# Python: Continuously running a section of a script

Tags: python, multithreading, email

I have written a python script that idles waiting for gmail to push a notification indicating that an email has been received. Then the contents are parsed and a database is searched, then database data is emailed back to the original sender.

Currently once an email is received, the script cannot process another email until the script has emailed back. I am wondering if there is a way for the script to be continually listening for an email. As at this point in time if two emails are received at similar times the second one will not be processed.

I think multi-threading might be a solution but I am not sure. Possibly create a new thread for the processEmail.py section of code below?

Sorry if I have explained badly, I am struggling to explain this adequately, feel free to ask for more information.

EDIT: Instead of down voting me could you help me by commenting telling me what more information I should include?

EDIT 2: Here is a code example, I am trying to have the ability to still listen for an email while an email is being processed in processEmail.py

```
import imaplib2
import time
import subprocess
from threading import *
from subprocess import call
import processEmail

class Idler(object):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.idle)
        self.M = conn
        self.event = Event()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

    def join(self):
        self.thread.join()

    def idle(self):
        while True:
            if self.event.isSet():
                return
            self.needsync = False
            def callback(args):
                if not self.event.isSet():
                    self.needsync = True
                    self.event.set()
            self.M.idle(callback=callback)
            self.event.wait()
            if self.needsync:
                self.event.clear()
                self.dosync()

    def dosync(self):
        print "An email has been received, please wait...\n"
        self.execute()

    def execute(self):
        processEmail.main()


M = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
M.login("email_address","email_pass")
M.select("Folder")
idler = Idler(M)
idler.start()
x = False
while not x: time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstartes the problem your are having

Comment: To prevent downvoting you should learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, I have made the suggested change.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly inherit from `threading.Thread` and override its `run` method:

```
class SomeTask(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # Will be executed in separate thread
```

Start the thread via its `start` method.

Communication between threads should be handled via [queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Comment: Thanks, I shall give this a go and get back to you! Luckily for me I don't want any communication between the threads.